# Why is 017 == 15 in C?

Tags: c, int, endianness

I've done a little bit of reading on endianness and its role in C, but nothing has really managed to clarify this for me. I'm just starting out with C and I saw this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 017;
    int y = 12;
    int diff = x - y;
    printf("diff is %d\n", diff);
    return 0;
}
```

and it asks what will print. I compiled and ran the example and got that diff is 3, so x is 15. I *sort of* see why this is, but would really appreciate if somebody really clarified it for me.

[1] I've looked for similar questions but haven't found any that explained the issue thoroughly. If someone could link me to one that would be good also.

Comment: Its an octal constant. (ie. base-8) 1*(8^1) + 7*(8^0) = 15 (base10

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Prefixing a number with `0` will tell the compiler to mark it as a number in octal (base 8)

Just like prefixing it with `0x` will tell it to use hex (base 16)

For example:

```
int x = 05;  // 5 in octal
int y = 5;   // 5 in decimal
int z = 0x5; // 5 in hex
```

Answer (score 1):

`017` is an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) constant if we look at the C99 draft standard section `6.4.4.1` *Integer constants* the grammar for *octal constant* is as follows:

```
octal-constant:
  0
  octal-constant octal-digit
octal-digit: one of
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

So any integer constant that starts `0` is in octal(*base 8*), this includes `0` itself.