# Why does bitwise AND operation 16 & 017 give an unexpected result?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int val = 16;
    printf("%d\t%d\t",val,val & 017);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output

```
16   0
```

and not

```
16   16
```

as I would expect for a boolean operation

```
16 AND 17 = 16
```

Comment: `017` is [in octal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19485548/1708801)

Comment: I am programming on bit level since years and I have the recommendation to work with hexadecimal numbers when doing bit operations. You will get used to recognize which hex number is which bit pattern (0xC = 0b1100 for example) and the hex numbers really nicely are always 4 bits a number. While for decimal numbers, I have huge troubles to know what for example is the bit pattern for 384... while 0x180 is easy (0b0001_1000_0000).

Comment: @CarstenGreiner Not that at least c++14 supports binary literals as well.

Answer (score 6):

The literal `017` is interpreted as octal representation because it starts with a `0`. For details on this see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485548/why-is-017-15-in-c). Now note that

```
(17)_8 == (15)_10 == (1111)_2
```

and then with `(16)_10 == (10000)_2` the result is clear.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out the problem is, that leading zeroes in numeric literals are going to have the value interpreted as base `8` (octal) numbers by the compiler.

`017` will actually render as `15` in decimal base, thus in decimal `16 AND 15 == 0`.

I've seen such failure mostly, when people tried to *"pretty format"* numeric declarations like

```
enum Values {
    A = 0001,
    B = 0008,
    C = 0016,
    // ...
};
```